# How to add a command in vim editor?

Tags: linux, vim

If suppose my source code file name is "foo.c".
While editing and debugging i always execute this command:-

> :!gcc -g foo.c -o foo;gdb foo

Can I add a custom command to Vim such that If i type ":debug" then the above command executes?
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes. Vim documentation, section 40.2, [Command-line mappings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2):

> The Vim editor enables you to define
>   your own commands.  You execute these
>   commands just like any other
>   Command-line mode command.    To
>   define a command, use the ":command"
>   command, as follows:
>
> :command DeleteFirst 1delete
>
> Now when you execute the command
>   ":DeleteFirst" Vim executes
>   ":1delete", which deletes the first
>   line.
>
> Note: User-defined commands must
>   start with a capital letter.  You
>   cannot    use ":X", ":Next" and
>   ":Print".  The underscore cannot be
>   used!  You    can use digits, but this
>   is discouraged.

Put that line in your `~/.vimrc` (minus the inital `:` of course) and it will be defined every time you start vim. Also, use `%:t` to make reference to the file being edited (writing `! gcc %:t` gets replaced by `! gcc foo.c`).

If you'd only like it to be defined for the one file, or for certain files, you want an [autocommand.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.3)

Comment: if you are replacing an existing command, you need to use `command!`.

Comment: If you want the command to take arguments this has to be specified. The document at the top of this answer addresses that. It isn't on by default.

Comment: `command!` is also useful when defining an autocommand (i.e. a file type specific command) otherwise error `E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it` will appear each time you press `ctrl-o` to jump back to a previous position or when viewing a git diff for example.

Comment: How can I define a command `:DoThing` that has different behaviour for `:DoThing` and for `:DoThing!` with the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 16):

Vim already has support for [Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html) (:make).  If you create one for your source, you can specify in it what you want done. Also, through ctags, Vim will be able to iterate through any errors found during compilation.

Answer (score 10):

### Add a user defined vi editor command:

This will make it so that when the user types `:Legend` in normal mode, a block of text is added under the cursor.

Step 1: Put this line into a file named ~/legend_header.txt`

```
this text will be added
```

Step 2: Put this command into your ~/.vimrc file (if the file doesn't exist, create it):

```
"The following command puts the contents of ~/legend_header.txt 
"under the cursor when the user types ":Legend" in normal mode.
command Legend :r ~/legend_header.txt
```

Step 3: Restart vi for the changes to take effect.  You're done.

**Test it**

Step 1: Open a new file in vi.  Be in the default "normal mode" in vi.  Type `:Legend`

Step 2: The contents of `~/legend_header.txt` should be added where the cursor is.

Comment: You don't need to restart vim as stated in step 3. You can use the command `:source ~/.vimrc` to reload.

Answer (score 1):

I use this command in my .vimrc to compile and execute the c code:

```
:command Gcc !set $1 `echo "%" | sed 's/\.c//g'` ;gcc -o $1 "%" ; chmod o+x $1; ./$1
```

, but for your needs you could put:

```
:command Gdb !set $1 `echo "%" | sed 's/\.c//g'` ;gcc -o $1 "%" ; gdb $1
```

You can be sure the name of the executable file will be the source name without .c extension.