# Insert Single Character in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim (7.2), there is a normal mode command `r` to replace a single character with another.  For example, typing `rX` will replace the one character under the cursor with `X` and then return you to normal mode.

Is there a normal-mode command to insert a single character and then return to normal mode?

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557893/making-inserting-a-single-character-in-vim-an-atomic-operation

Comment: See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_single_character for comprehensive solution.

Comment: There's no single command, but I use `sX, esc, P`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MelBurslan is correct that this feature does not natively exist, but creating a user-defined command is not really the way to go about creating it.  I tinkered for a few minutes and came up with this:

```
:nmap <silent> ,s "=nr2char(getchar())<cr>P
```

Which uses some Vim trickery involving "putting" text from a register, in this case the "expression" register. The expression being plugged into the register is "`nr2char(getchar())`" which will return a single character string.

The reason I built the mapping this way is that getting user input "midway through" a mapping is tricky and can behave unpredictably; even this mapping will drop the cursor down to the status area while waiting for the user to type a character.

Comment: How does one use this? And is this repeatable?

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to Johnny for giving us this terrific answer in the comments below:

```
":nmap <C-i> i_<Esc>r"
```

That maps Control + i to insert a single character, and it does it very concisely.

In your vimrc file, this will look like:

```
nnoremap <C-i> i_<Esc>r
```

I changed my mapping to use space, and you can change yours to your preferred key(s):

```
nnoremap <Space> i_<Esc>r
```

Comment: This is the most concise and simple answer.

Comment: This is simple and makes sense, but for whatever reason it doesn't work as intended when I put it in my .vimrc. When I do it "by hand" (type `i_<Esc>r`) it works, but when used by the mapping it leaves me in normal mode, with the cursor on the `_`.

It's probably a question of my vim config, but for the record I'm on neovim 0.9.1 on OSX

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no such function in any widely distributed incarnation of vi editor but, vim has a facility to create custom commands. It has previously been discussed here: [in this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/93492/how-to-add-a-command-in-vim-editor)

You might be able to create your custom command doing what you wish to do.

Comment: Here's the command to map Ctrl-I to insert a single character: ":nmap <C-i> i_<esc>r"

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is using the Cut <kbd>x</kbd> and Put <kbd>p</kbd> commands.  Say that `*` is the character you want to insert.  Insert it using <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  Then hit <kbd>x</kbd>.  That will cut the character.  Now, you can hit <kbd>p</kbd> to put the single character.  If you need to insert that character 300 times, you can type: `300p`.

Comment: Did you just say that having to press a total of 5 keys is a 'simple way' of typing a character?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is great.  But given "e" move you to the end of a word, I like this better with one right move "l" as here

`:nmap <C-i> li_<Esc>r`

or in .vimrc

`nnoremap <C-i> li_<Esc>r`